# C++ WinApi OpenCV webcam - how to get and save all pixels values in array from Mat frame and how to show it later

Tags: c++, opencv, winapi, frame, pixel

I know its very long title but I have many questions.
There's my full code: https://pastebin.com/GyGiFGNb
But I have more questions to that part:

```
DWORD WINAPI Thread_no_1(LPVOID lpParam){
//int data = 0;
//hwnd = *((HWND*)lpParam);
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if (!cap.isOpened()) // check if we succeeded
    return -1;
namedWindow("video", 1);

//|| while data
//for (;;)
do
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    imshow("video", frame);
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
} while (przelacznik == 1);
cap.release();}
```

I'm trying to get frame pixel values for save them into array (unsigned char type array) and next compress the image (into jpg).
My questions are:

1. How to get picture size to know how big array should be? (3 * width because 3 values for each pixel?)
2. How to get and save every pixel values from Mat frame into array? (I've found some Python loops but not C++)
3. Should I do all this in that thread or I'll be better in main program but then how send frame outside?
4. Can I show a picture saved in array in window?
5. What library can help me with compressing an image saved by this way?

PS. How put my opencv camera window into my main window?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using `imwrite` to save the image as a jpg?

Comment: But can I compress frame before imwrite?  
Can I show compressed frame before imwrite? I've tried imwrite before with poor result (maybe I did something wrong), then someone told me I should make array and work on pixels directly. He showed me wiki page with jpg compression and rules about it. My program is for "Lossy compression"

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from your question that you wanted the compressed image in memory rather than just saving it in a compressed jpeg format. Either way, your question is answered in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html).

Comment: Compressed in memory but when I'll do that an image will have less resolution or something?